# Unable to track down error for WCF client created with CreateChannelWithIssuedToken

Tags: c#, wcf, ws-security, ws-trust

This is a followup of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442354/signed-soap-header-has-two-binarysecuritytokens-when-in-fact-it-could-and-shoul). Might not be directly related to that.

I am trying to call a web service secured with a token (federated security, WS-Trust 1.3) which I obtain from a Secure Token Service. I have the `SecurityToken` (generic XML) and I create a `ChannelFactory<T>` on which I then call `CreateChannelWithIssuedToken`.

The actual error appears when I attempt to invoke a service method. The message is very short and I actually have no idea where to look next: `MessageSecurityException` and message **Unable to create token reference**. Well, that can mean anything.

The relevant code:

```
var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false; 

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(
    binding, 
    new EndpointAddress("..."));
factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;

var token = STSClient.Issue();
_channel = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
```

And calling the service is:

```
var svcParams = ...;

//MessageSecurityException is thrown here
var svcResponse = _channel.SomeServiceMethod(params);
```

What I would like to know is where can I look next. What could cause this error ?

Additional details:

1. The error is thrown before any request is made to the server (checked with Fiddler).
2. The server is not WCF based. It's some service that complies to WS-Trust and WS-Security.

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark but my guess would be a trust issue with the server running the WCF service and the cert used to sign the request.  I.E.  the server does not trust the signing CA.

Comment: @BenRobinson: Thanks, but the error happens even before the request is sent out. I'm guessing it's when the SOAP message is being built. Also, the server side is not WCF (actually, I don't know what it is). I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the issue was insufficient configuration of the federation binding. Because I already have the token and it is already signed I should have set the `IssuedKeyType` on the message security to `SecurityKeyType.BearerKey`.

By playing further with this turns out that `Unable to create token reference` is thrown every time when there are, well, not enough details to embed the token in the request (typically it's missing configuration on the binding or on the binding's `TransportSecurityBindingElement`).

This does not completely solve the entire "calling the service with a token" issue, but it does solve this particular error:

```
var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
```